# Android studio new project buttons are off and disabled

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android development, and i have a very simple question about **andriod studio** program.

I have installed every thing that is needed to open it,

But now , when i want to create a new project ***i can't continue*** , check this shot screen :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFUi3.png

The next button is disabled !

What should i do to do next ?

Comment: You haven't selected a compile version, maybe that's whats stopping you

Comment: @Juan-devtopia.coop the compile versian is EMPTY ! and there is nothing in it ! what to do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because you don't have any SDK's installed.

In Android Studio, go to tools -> Android -> SDK manager and download the API's you need for your new project, then try to start a new project again. You will be able to pick an SDK to compile against after this.

Answer (score 0):

Download your android tools, libraries and platforms that you will need to start your projects from SDK Manager