# Whenever I start a new project I am unable to change my activity and layout file name in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5.3

As you can see the next button is disable. So the android studio uses the default name  mainactivity.java and activity_main.xml for activity and layout respectively. So how can I change the name of the activity and layout?  I am using the android studio on my other pc that let me to change the name of the activity and layout during the configuration of the project.

[image]

Comment: avoid the whitespace for your project path sais the error in your image.

Comment: i am use the same path on my other pc it works fine for me. any other solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Providing custom activity name instead of main activity in android studio while creating new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194910/providing-custom-activity-name-instead-of-main-activity-in-android-studio-while)

Comment: i already know about this. And tell me which version of android studio r you using?

Comment: do you have the necessary sdks installed??? check  this-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032188/android-studio-new-project-buttons-are-off-and-disabled/24032769#24032769

Comment: yes i do have necessary sdk installed. i have created other apps and they run.

Comment: It's annoying that Android Studio makes you go back and refeactor the default name. Why does it not let you choose at the time of the project creation (like the older versions used to)?